# Can you find all the Star Wars words in this wordsearch?

Tags: word-search

A simple enough challenge. This wordsearch contains a number of words...

> "*... connected with the discovery of Anakin Skywalker*"

**Can you find (and name) all of them?**

[image]
<sub><sup>**Image courtesy of Pedigree Pocket Money Treat - Star Wars: First Edition**</sup></sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found **Slaves**, **Battles**, **Tatooine**, **Republic**, **Disguise**. And I like to think he *peed* himself a bit in fear when the lava started burning him.

*Peed* is supposed to be **Speeder**

Added on **Senate** and **Obi** 
**(Prophecy**, **Coruscant**, **Watto**, **Naboo**, **Invasion** and **Gungans** found by Krazy)

**Droids** added from Toast

Final word, **Bongo** from APrough

[image]

Comment: You can find "Coruscant" going upwards from the P of "peed", "Gungans" going backwards along the bottom, and "Prophecy" going up from the bottom-right corner.

Comment: Deep/Peed isn't one of the answers. Sorry :-) nor is Bane

Comment: I figured it wasn't an answer but I added it for fun ;) - Thanks Krazy I'll toss it on. And I am not sure what you mean by Bane

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Bane

Comment: You can find "Bane" going upwards through the "N" of Tatooine. Try going down from the "N", though... hint hint ;)

Comment: ^ Thanks, and not sure if it is supposed to just be Obi, but cannot find any other instance of his name or Kenobi. Same with Padame not being seen.

Comment: I just noticed "Invasion" going up from the I of "Republic", I can't see anything else in there currently.

Comment: Oh, here's another one: Watto (Anakin's owner) can be found going up to the second O of "Tatooine"

Comment: `DROIDS` ends where `SLAVES` ends.

Comment: I think `PEED` is supposed to be `SPEED`

Comment: Still missing a couple and Obi isn't one of the ones on my list

Comment: @EngineerToast - You're *nearly* there with that one.

Comment: Well Obi was important :P And it's supposed to be speeder I see.. I'm still leaving peed circled ;)

Comment: I also see Qui (underneath Naboo)

Comment: @APrough I noticed that as well but I figured if "Obi" wasn't correct then neither was "Qui"

Comment: What about Bongo?  That was the name of the Gungan speeder, if I recall.

Comment: Don't know, maybe have OP confirm that one... And while I assume it's not one, Elim is in top right, short for elimination and he did do quite a bit of that

Comment: @APrough - You are correct, Sir; https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAryr.png / https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1C7l.png